# Getting category parent ID

Tags: kentico

The code below returns me a list of categories which a page has been assigned to.

```
var categories = DocumentCategoryInfoProvider.GetDocumentCategories(documentId).Columns("CMS_Category.CategoryID, CategoryDisplayName");
```

I want to know their parent display name for each category in the list. So I can do some selection while looping the category list.

Any solution to get to know its parent for each category in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add in one more column `CategoryParentID`

```
var categories = DocumentCategoryInfoProvider.GetDocumentCategories(documentId).Columns("CMS_Category.CategoryID, CategoryDisplayName, CategoryParentID");
```

And you can get the category parent based on the `CategoryParentID` that you got.